# How do I in vanilla javascript: selectors,events and the need of $(this)

Tags: javascript, events

I have 3 pictures cropped  by `span.main{overflow:hidden}`. User can pan the span with touch events and explore the hidden parts of the picture.

Code so far:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {

var box = document.querySelector('.main'); 

        box.addEventListener("touchstart", onStart, false);
        box.addEventListener("touchmove", onMove, false);
        box.addEventListener("touchend", onEnd, false);

});

var startOffsetX, startOffsetY;
var moving = false;

function getPos(ev) {
return { 
    x: ev.touches ? ev.touches[0].clientX : ev.clientX, 
    y: ev.touches ? ev.touches[0].clientY : ev.clientY
};
}

function onStart(ev) {
moving = true;
var box = document.querySelector('.main');// I need something like $(this)
var pos = getPos(ev);
startOffsetX = pos.x + box.scrollLeft;
startOffsetY = pos.y + box.scrollTop;
if (ev.preventDefault)
    ev.preventDefault();
else
    ev.returnValue = false;
}

function onMove(ev) {
if (moving) {
    var pos = getPos(ev);
    var x = startOffsetX - pos.x;
    var y = startOffsetY - pos.y;
    var box = document.querySelector('.main'); //  I need something like $(this) 
    box.scrollLeft = x;
    box.scrollTop = y;
    if (ev.preventDefault)
        ev.preventDefault();
    else
        ev.returnValue = false;
}
} 
function onEnd(ev) {
if (moving) {
    moving = false;
}
}
```

The problem is that only the first thumbnail works as expected. I've tried:

-querySelector only returns the first element so if I add ID's and `querySelector('#box1,#box2,#box3')` should work. Nein. I thing I have a 'this' problem on the functions...

-Place events (as Apple suggests) inline `<div class="box" onStart="ontouchstartCallback( ev);" ontouchend="onEnd( ev );"ontouchmove="onMove( ev );" > <img></div>` looked like a solution yet...My guess, because of 'this' again...

Comment: Apple suggests to use inline events? What. The. Hell.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/HandlingEvents/HandlingEvents.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006511-SW1

Comment: Does not look like a suggestion but rather like a simple example where inline events are the most convenient way...

Comment: I'm hungry so excuse the bad mood yet online dictionaries seems to agree that 'Suggests' mean ' To offer for consideration or action'. So yes, apple suggests me to take for consideration inline events.

Comment: Suggests implies "to offer for consideration," but offering for consideration does not imply a suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use the `querySelectorAll` method instead. It returns all matched elements in the subtree instead of only the first one (which is what `querySelector` does). Then loop through them using a `for` loop.

```
var elements = document.querySelectorAll('.main');
for (var i = 0, ii = elements.length; i < ii; ++i) {
  var element = elements[i];
  element.ontouchstart = onStart;
  // ...
}
```

The other approach you can take (and it is probably a better one) is to use event delegation and set the event listeners on a parent element and decide which of the pictures is being manipulated by checking the `target` property of each event.

```
<div id="pictures">
  <span class="main"><img /></span>
  <span class="main"><img /></span>
  <span class="main"><img /></span>
</div>

var parent = document.getElementById('pictures');
parent.ontouchstart = function (e) {
  var box = e.target.parentNode; // parentNode because e.target is an Image
  if (box.className !== 'main') return;

  onStart(e, box);
};
```

Comment: Thank you Jan. Can you kindly provide an example of a for loop and querySelectorAll ? I'm trying the second approach right now but it's not working as I don't fully understand it, need more time. Let's see if some other good soul can provide a better explanation before accepting this answer.